# Mathematical functions on fractions

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, rational-numbers

I have been challenged by @nhgrif to write a Fraction class to better my understanding of OOP. I have found an interesting challenge [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690663/c-fractions-class) (I apologize that the source is not mentioned, I was not able to find it either).

> **Problem statement**: Create a class named Fraction having two integer
>   data members named for a fraction's numerator and denominator. The
>   class' default constructor should provide both data members with
>   default values of 1 if no explicit initialization is provided. The
>   constructor must also prohibit a 0 denominator value. Include member
>   functions for displaying an object's data values and mathematical
>   functions capable of adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing
>   two Fraction objects.

I have written this [on Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/lBf83A) hence explaining why everything is in one file. I have made a slight change to the default values given no parameters, as I have been told a `0/1` default fraction makes more sense than `1/1`.

I have also added a simple but potentially useful method to cast a fraction into its decimal value.

I named my fraction variables using a pattern like `fractionN_D` where N is numerator and D is denominator. It seemed short enough to be practical (as compared to `fractionThreeFourths`) while still carrying meaning. Any suggestion on that is of course welcome.

```
 class Fraction {
    private final int numerator;
    private final int denominator;

    Fraction() {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    Fraction (int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        if (denominator == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator cannot be zero.");
        } else {
            this.denominator = denominator;
        }
    }

    public String getFraction() {
        return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
    public double getFractionDecimal() {
        return ((double) numerator) / denominator;
    }

    // Mathematical functions

    public String addFraction(Fraction otherFraction) {
        // Sum formula: a/b + c/d = (ad + cb)/bd
        int a = this.numerator;
        int b = this.denominator;
        int c = otherFraction.numerator;
        int d = otherFraction.denominator;
        return ((a*d) + (c*b)) + "/" + (b*d);
    }

    public String subtractFraction(Fraction otherFraction) {
        // Subtraction formula: a/b - c/d = (ad - cb)/bd
        int a = this.numerator;
        int b = this.denominator;
        int c = otherFraction.numerator;
        int d = otherFraction.denominator;
        return ((a*d) - (c*b)) + "/" + (b*d);
    }

    public String multiplyByFraction(Fraction otherFraction) {
        // Multiplication formula: a/b * c/d = ac/bd
        int a = this.numerator;
        int b = this.denominator;
        int c = otherFraction.numerator;
        int d = otherFraction.denominator;
        return (a*c) + "/" + (b*d);
    }

    public String divideByFraction(Fraction otherFraction) {
        // Division formula: (a/b) / (c/d) = ad/bc
        int a = this.numerator;
        int b = this.denominator;
        int c = otherFraction.numerator;
        int d = otherFraction.denominator;
        return (a*d) + "/" + (b*c);
    }
}

class TestFraction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction fraction3_4 = new Fraction(3,4);
        Fraction fraction2_3 = new Fraction(2,3);

        System.out.println("F1: " + fraction3_4.getFraction() + " Dec: " + fraction3_4.getFractionDecimal());
        System.out.println("F2: " + fraction2_3.getFraction() + " Dec: " + fraction2_3.getFractionDecimal() + "\n");
        System.out.println("F1 + F2: " + fraction3_4.addFraction(fraction2_3));
        System.out.println("F2 + F1: " + fraction2_3.addFraction(fraction3_4) + "\n");
        System.out.println("F1 - F2: " + fraction3_4.subtractFraction(fraction2_3));
        System.out.println("F2 - F1: " + fraction2_3.subtractFraction(fraction3_4) + "\n");
        System.out.println("F1 * F2: " + fraction3_4.multiplyByFraction(fraction2_3));
        System.out.println("F2 * F1: " + fraction2_3.multiplyByFraction(fraction3_4) + "\n");
        System.out.println("F1 / F2: " + fraction3_4.divideByFraction(fraction2_3));
        System.out.println("F2 / F1: " + fraction2_3.divideByFraction(fraction3_4));
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is as follows:

> ```
> F1: 3/4 Dec: 0.75
> F2: 2/3 Dec: 0.6666666666666666
>
> F1 + F2: 17/12
> F2 + F1: 17/12
>
> F1 - F2: 1/12
> F2 - F1: -1/12
>
> F1 * F2: 6/12
> F2 * F1: 6/12
>
> F1 / F2: 9/8
> F2 / F1: 8/9
> ```

Comment: The case for using `1/1` as default is that this is the identity value for multiplication/division. It also avoids one vector by which a fraction produces divide by zero errors as a component of other divisions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Public

```
class Fraction {
```

I get it that you're writing this in ideone so you cannot do this, but for the record, that class should be `public class`

```
Fraction() {
```

This constructor should be `public`

```
Fraction (int numerator, int denominator) {
```

This constructor should also be `public`

#### Constructor calls constructor

As your `Fraction()` constructor is essentially initializing it with specific values you can call one constructor from another

```
public Fraction() {
    this(0, 1);
}
```

#### Throw or else

```
if (denominator == 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator cannot be zero.");
} else {
```

If you throw an exception inside the `if`, there's no need to write `else` explicitly. Just put the code that is currently in the `else` after the `if`-statement. Like this:

```
public Fraction (int numerator, int denominator) {
    this.numerator = numerator;
    if (denominator == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator cannot be zero.");
    }
    this.denominator = denominator;
}
```

*(I do however agree about @Jeroen's answer about putting the denominator check first)*

#### Returning something useful

```
public String addFraction(Fraction otherFraction) {
```

What do you get when you add a `Fraction` with another `Fraction`? (Mathematically speaking)

You get... A STRING!

No you don't. You get a `Fraction`

These mathematical methods you have written here should really return a new `Fraction` instance.

And you don't need to have `Fraction` in the name. Simply `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `divide` is enough.

#### MOAR METHODS!

I would recommend adding a `toString` method, in your case the implementation is simple:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getFraction();
}
```

I would also like to see a `normalize` method that returns a fraction that has been reduced as much as possible, for example:

- 18/4 --> 9/2
- 24/4 --> 6/1
- 4/8 --> 1/2

I am also missing `public int getNumerator()` and `public int getDenominator()`, which would make your `Fraction` class much more useful.

Comment: Funny you mention getNominator() etc. I actually had those in originally but removed them because I didn't think they'd be useful. Thanks for the great review!

Comment: Er... getNumerator() I meant lol.

Comment: A `gcd()` function (Greatest Common Denominator) would be a great help with normalising the fraction. They are very simple to write!

Comment: Why would `getNumerator()` and `getDenominator()` be useful?  1/2 and 2/4 and 16/32 are the same fraction, not different ones.

Comment: @MichaelShaw Why would they not be useful? And I wouldn't say that they are truly equal, objectorientally speaking. Let's say you have some fraction and want to create the same fraction but increasing the denominator one step, right now there's no way you can do that, and `1/3` is not the same as `2/5`

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Adding one to the denominator isn't an operation on fractions.  0.5 is a fraction.  Is adding 1 to the denominator going to give 1/3?  5/11?  And there is a way to do this sort of thing with the constructor already, just use a for loop with `new Fraction(1, i);`.  From an OO perspective, you're coupling the interface with its implementation.  I also think asking "why not?" to justify adding code is a bad idea; YAGNI and all that.

Comment: @MichaelShaw Not providing the two getters is a restriction. Providing the two getters causes no harm at all. I see no reason to *not* provide them. Even though it might be a case of YAGNI, a `Fraction` class like this one seems to be library-purposed. I would personally not use a `Fraction` class from some library that did not have two getters.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Not making the numerator and denominator naked public variables is also a restriction.  Restrictions aren't necessarily bad.  I would consider adding dead code that gains nothing to be harm, even though in this case it isn't a whole lot.  I'd really like to argue that the implementation could change, but for this specific example that seems unlikely.  In general, implementations can and do change, so while it might not cause *much* harm in *this* case, exposing the implementation is not the good OO the OP asked the question to learn about.

Comment: @MichaelShaw Agreed. The implementation could e.g. change to one always normalizing the fraction, which would break any code using the getters.

Answer (score 7):

This is in addition to Simon's remarks.

---

It's good practice to validate arguments as the first course of action in the body. Therefore I would suggest this instead:

```
Fraction (int numerator, int denominator) {
    if (denominator == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator cannot be zero.");
    }

    this.denominator = denominator;
    this.numerator = numerator;       
}
```

---

Instead of `getFraction()` and `getFractionDecimal()` I would use `toString()` for the string representation and `getDecimal()` for the decimal one.

Comment: Your second point: `getFraction()` reads like it would return a `Fraction` (`public Fraction getFraction() { return this; }`)

Comment: Yes, I noticed it later when other answers mentioned that but I forgot to adjust the naming here. I've done this now, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It's good that you made your class immutable.  I'd make the class and its constructors `public` as well.

If you offer a default constructor at all, you should chain them:

```
public Fraction() {
    this(0, 1);
}
```

… but consider offering constants `ZERO` and `ONE` instead.

Instead of `IllegalArgumentException`, consider throwing `ArithmeticException` — that's what happens when you try to divide by zero.

The `getFraction()` and `getFractionDecimal()` methods are confusingly named.  I'd call them `toString()` and `toDouble()`, respectively.

Your arithmetic functions could have shorter names, e.g. `add(Fraction addend)`.  They should each return another `Fraction`, not a `String`.  (You could always call `toString()` on the result, but parsing a `String` back into a `Fraction` is relatively hard.)

The results should be in reduced form.  Arguably, that should be the case for all `Fraction`s, and enforced in the constructor, so that `(new Fraction(2, 4)).toString()` produces `"1/2"`.

Note that dividing by another fraction has the possibility of dividing by zero.

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion would be to store a fraction rather than output a string, and have a fraction output method (toString or such) that would return the string.

Also, a method that ensures you have the lowest possible denominator would be good, as looking at your code I think you would potentially be missing that - getting 12/24 looks possible, while you should get 1/2 for that result. My math brain is rusty right now so I can't say what the most effective and efficient method for this would be.

Also, if a fraction's denominator becomes 1 (say result is 12/12, which simplifies to 1/1) it should return only a whole number.

And finally, when you have greater than 1 total (11/10 for instance) it should output 1 1/10 or have the option to do so somehow - your choice though, and a step beyond the scope of the challenge I think.

I think with those changes you would be well on your way to a functional Fraction class. I do like it though, looks nice and clean at least.

Comment: I really like the suggestion of outputting `1 1/10`

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> public String divideByFraction(Fraction otherFraction) {
>     // Division formula: (a/b) / (c/d) = ad/bc
>     int a = this.numerator;
>     int b = this.denominator;
>     int c = otherFraction.numerator;
>     int d = otherFraction.denominator;
>     return (a*d) + "/" + (b*c);
> }
> ```

Taking in mind the comments made by *Simon*, *200_success*, and others, we need to fix this particular method up a bit.

If `this` is equal to zero (zero numerator) or `otherFraction` is equal to zero (zero numerator), the result will be some number over 0.  If we were actually returning a Fraction, then we'd be constructing one in here, and the constructor (and thus, this method) will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.  Java probably has a `DivisionByZero` except, and this is actually what we want to use, so let's check for zero numerators/divisors.  If `this` has a numerator of zero, we can just quickly return a zero fraction.  If `otherFraction` has a numerator of zero, we need to throw a division by zero exception.

So, something like this:

```
public Fraction divide(Fraction otherFraction) {
    if (otherFraction.numerator == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Division by zero.")
    }

    int numerator = this.numerator * otherFraction.denominator;
    int denominator = this.denominator * otherFraction.denominator;

    return new this(numerator, denominator);
}
```

---

And fundamentally, we have to ask ourselves, should the math functions return a new `Fraction` or mutate the current one?

You *could* make the argument for something like this:

```
public void divide(Fraction divisor) {
    if (divisor.numerator == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Division by zero.")
    }

    this.numerator *= divisor.denominator;
    this.denominator *= divisor.numerator;
    this.reduce();
}

static public Fraction divide(Fraction dividend, Fraction divisor) {
    int numerator = dividend.numerator * divisor.denominator;
    int denominator = dividen.denominator * divisor.numerator;
    return new this(numerator, denominator);
}
```

So, now usage would look like this:

```
Fraction threeFifths = new Fraction(3,5);
Fraction oneHalf = new Fraction(1,2);
threeFifths.divide(oneHalf); // three fifths is now 6/5
Fraction twelveFifths = Fraction.divide(threeFifths,oneHalf);
```

---

#### What's missing?

Here's a list of methods that are missing that could be added...

```
public float toFloat()
public int toInt()
```

... etc, these may or may not be particularly useful.

More constructors...

```
public Fraction(int numerator) {
    return this(numerator,1);
}

public Fraction(double d) {
    // this IS possible...
}
```

Some factory methods:

```
static public Fraction Zero() {
    return this(0,1);
}

static public Fraction One() {
    return this(1,1);
}
```

Math methods for other types:

```
public void divide(int divisor) {
    this.divide(new Fraction(divisor));
}
```

...etc

Comment: 0/0 is undefined, so divisor = 0 must be checked before shirt-circuiting dividend = 0

Answer (score 4):

Evaluating further on [Simon André Forsberg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-andr%C3%A9-forsberg) point about **Returning something useful** in his pretty good [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/83247/29371).

Let us take a look at the `addFraction()` method

> ```
> public String addFraction(Fraction otherFraction) {
>     // Sum formula: a/b + c/d = (ad + cb)/bd
>     int a = this.numerator;
>     int b = this.denominator;
>     int c = otherFraction.numerator;
>     int d = otherFraction.denominator;
>     return ((a*d) + (c*b)) + "/" + (b*d);
> }
> ```

it would be very easy to change this to returning a `Fraction` instead of a `String`

```
public Fraction add(Fraction otherFraction) {
    // Sum formula: a/b + c/d = (ad + cb)/bd
    int a = this.numerator;
    int b = this.denominator;
    int c = otherFraction.numerator;
    int d = otherFraction.denominator;
    if(b == d) {
        return new Fraction(a + c, b);
    }
    return new Fraction(a * d + c * b, b * d);
}
```

and together with a overridden `toString()` method we don't need the formerly returned `String` anymore.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if(denominator == 1) {
        return numerat.toString();
    }
    return numerator + "/" + denominator;
}
```

which I would prefer over the former `getFraction()` method, because this isn't returning a `Fraction`.

This together would make e.g. this possible:

```
Fraction first = new Fraction(12, 3);
Fraction second = new Fraction(6, 3);
Fraction sum = first.add(second);

System.out.print(first + " + " + second + " = " + sum);
```

Which would output

```
12/3 + 6/3 = 18/3
```

Comment: Why so many parentheses in `new Fraction(((a*d) + (c*b)), (b*d))`? Also, the string concatenation in the call to `System.out.println()` does not need explicit `.toString()`.

Comment: @200_success Good question. Will edit tomorrow when back in the office. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly I would say the proper mathematical name for this class is `Rational` but perhaps that's just a matter of taste.

Secondly I would put the object in a canonical format.
For example I would only allow the numerator to be negative. If the denominator is passed into a constructor as negative I would negate the numerator sign and use `java.lang.Math.abs(denominator)`.

I would also divide numerator and denominator by their greatest common divisor (gcd) to make sure objects have a unique and simple form.

In that event your `equals` method is trivial and you also stave off overflow.
Without reduction to simplest terms you will encounter overflow very quickly.